# Running two parallel.foreach() together

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, task-parallel-library

I have a background worker which invokes parallel threads for list items

```
 doWork()
    {
    Parallel.foreach(list1, a=>
    {
       while(true)
       {
             //do some operations
       }
    });

    Parallel.foreach(list2, b=>
    {
        while(true)
        {
            //do some operations
        } 
    });
    }
```

If i want to run both of these lists together parallelly, should i create another thread as their parent or anyother way?? i am getting both the lists separately so combining them is not an option.And i am running infinite loops inside both of them.

Comment: Create two tasks and  then `Task.WaitAll`

Comment: `Action<object> action = (object obj) =>
        {
           //put the parallel.foreach here
        };`  and another action for the second `parallel.foreach` and then run the tasks and call for `Task.WaitAll` rt??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tasks to run the two loops on separate threads.  Use normal `foreach` loops.

```
var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    foreach(var a in list1)
    {
        //do some operations
    }
});

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
{
    foreach(var a in list1)
    {
        //do some operations
    }
});

// This will block the thread until both tasks have completed
Task.WaitAll(t1, t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two seperate threads for the two 'foreach' loops.

Comment: Explicitly creating threads is usually not a good idea if you can use TPL.